# using an overlapping months concept for fiscal year

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on understanding my customer pathway inside our company. We want to look at the overlapping months Jan2021-June2022(Fiscal year22), then Jan2022-June2023(Fiscal year23). But my calendar table calculates only fiscal year for 12 months. so, I have tried a lot of dynamic queries but
I cannot achieve the desired results. I can achieve the results if I look at the just one Fiscal year22 but I need to make it automated so there will not be a need for the custom queries for date range.

```
SELECT 
    CUSTOMER_SK,
    dd. fiscal_year_num as FISCALYEAR,
    CASE
    WHEN MAX(is_new_customer_encounter) = TRUE THEN 'NEW'
    WHEN MAX(is_reengaged_customer_encounter) = TRUE THEN 'REENGAGED'
    WHEN MAX(is_retained_customer_encounter) = TRUE THEN 'RETAINED'
    ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
    END AS CUSTOMER_CATEGORY
FROM
    refined.core.calendar dd 
    join enriched.analytics.encounter_system_level sys 
        on dd.calendar_date = sys.encounter_ts::date or dd.year_num= =year(sys.encounter_ts)
WHERE
    dd.fiscal_year_num between 2023 and 2024
GROUP BY 
    1,2;
```

Any thoughts on this issue?

I did try dynamic date ctes but nothing is working.

This is my desired result

| Customers | date visited | Fiscal year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| customer 1 | 01/25/2023 | 2023 |
| customer 2 | 07/11/2023 | 2024 |
| customer 1 | 01/25/2023 | 2024 |

Comment: I have removed the ANSI SQL tags, since neither the question nor the answer is ANSI SQL compliant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to create your own version of the calendar table with your dates in it. The example below gets the base dataset from the existing calendar table. It then unions it with a duplicate of the calendar dataset for the first 6 months of each year with the fiscal year reduced by 1.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/82b619)

```
WITH FiscalCalendar AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM refined.core.calendar
    UNION ALL
    SELECT calendar_date, fiscal_year_num - 1
    FROM refined.core.calendar
    WHERE MONTH(calendar_date) >= 1 AND MONTH(calendar_date) <= 6
)
```

Comment: Hey Chris,  I did try this cte but again it still gives only the 12 months as fiscal year instead of 18 months .     with calen as (
    SELECT calendar_date,fiscal_year_num
    FROM refined.core.calendar
    UNION ALL
    SELECT calendar_date, fiscal_year_num + 1
    FROM refined.core.calendar
    WHERE MONTH(calendar_date) >= 1 AND MONTH(calendar_date) <= 6
    )
select * from calen 
where calendar_Date >= '01/01/2022'
limit 500

Comment: Woops. I had made a mistake. Updated answer and posted a fiddle.

Comment: I cannot look at the fiddle . Is there a way to look at it ?

Comment: 0


basically Jan 2022 -June 2023 should be as fiscal year 2023, and Jan 2023 - June 2024 should be a fiscal year 2024 but instead I get Jan 1, 2024, as fiscal year 2023 which is not the way I want the dates to be.

Comment: with calen as (
    SELECT calendar_date,  fiscal_year_num
    FROM refined.core.calendar
    UNION ALL
    SELECT calendar_date, fiscal_year_num - 1
    FROM refined.core.calendar
    WHERE MONTH(calendar_date) >= 1 AND MONTH(calendar_date) <= 6)

    select * from calen 
    where fiscal_year_num = 2023
    limit 1000

Comment: Thats what I have in the updates answer